# TypeDescriptor Attribute Retrieval Inconsistency

Tags: c#, typedescriptor

I found something interesting while playing around with `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor`:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Enum Enum { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person();

        var typeDescriptionProvider = TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(person, new DescriptionAttribute("Some description of this person"));

        // Returns no attributes if person is a *struct* instance,
        // but does return the DescriptionAttribute if person is a *class* instance
    --> var descriptionAttributes = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(person).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().ToList();

        // Always returns the DescriptionAttribute
        var descriptionAttributesUsingTdp = typeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(person).GetAttributes().OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When the definition of `Person` is a class, the line of code with the `-->` finds and returns the `DescriptionAttribute` just fine.

When I change `Person` to a struct, the code does not find the `DescriptionAttribute`.

[image: Why?]

What is the rationale behind this difference? Is there some magic going on for reference types that is absent for value types?

I know that the line of code below the `-->` returns the attribute regardless of whether the instance of Person is a class or a struct. This is because [the `TypeDescriptionProvider` returned by the `AddAttributes()` method call was the one that performed the addition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xazd050.aspx).

Comment: Works for me. Do you see the behavior with the code you posted (and with `public struct Person`), or did you perhaps oversimplify the problem (thus fixing it)?

Comment: Strange! I've edited the question to include a screenshot of the problem. Any reason why I would be experiencing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why doesn't `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(person)` return the attribute when `Person` is a struct?**

[`TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xazd050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edecex5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use reference equality to find objects in `TypeDescriptor`'s internal cache. If `Person` is a class, then the `person` arguments in those two method calls reference the same instance. However, if `Person` is a struct, then the `person` arguments get boxed independently into *different* instances, so `GetAttributes` is unable to find the original `person`.

If `person` is only boxed once, then the code works as expected:

```
object person = new Person();  // `object` instead of `var`
```

**Why does `typeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(person).GetAttributes()` always return the attribute?**

The [`TypeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tba4t3b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation  isn't clear (at least to me), but note that you can apparently pass *anything* to `typeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor` — like `42` (a struct) or `"Hello, World!"` (a class) — and get your attribute back:

```
var descriptionAttributesUsingTdp = typeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(42)
    .GetAttributes().OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().ToList();
// descriptionAttributesUsingTdp.Count == 1
```

Based on this behavior, my guess is that the `typeDescriptionProvider` returned by `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(person, ...)` is not associated with the `person`. Instead, it represents a plug-in that can add your attribute to *any* object, and `GetTypeDescriptor` is the method that does so.

Comment: Thank you for the well-researched answer, @MichaelLiu.